# How can I read audio files directory in Python?

Tags: python, audio, datadirectory

I have a folder stored on the my desktop, and its contains 19 audio file in WAV format. When I execute the following code for read the audio file the output for len(audio-files) was 0..but its must be 19. How can I solve this problem???

```
from glob import glob
data_dir = './audio featur-extraction\audio-setA/'
audio_files = glob(data_dir + '*.wav')
len(audio_files)
```

output: `0`.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want the audio data.

```
import wave, os, glob
zero = []
path = '/path/to/directory'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.wav')):
    w = wave.open(filename, 'r')
    d = w.readframes(w.getnframes())
    zero.append(d)
    w.close()
```

Comment: I want to extract features from audio and save it in the excel file, but the output for len(audio_files) was 0, its return excel file with no value.. I need solve for this problem.@Ahmer Arain

Comment: @softangle it’s not good form to move the goal posts of your question. I recommend editing the original question to clarify the problem your are facing.